# Function does not read last value

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, datatable, dataset, dataview

I am developing a program for a chain of restaurants, they should normally be able to calculate their guestcount and sales through a vb.net application with a connection to dbf files.
My dataset gets filled in correctly as is my datatable (checked by filling in datarowview = right data)
But then I get a problem, in all my functions using my datatable, the datatable skips the final value, in this case it is all values from a month so it either skips 31 or day 30.
Tried while, Tried for each, debugged alot (how i found it was the last value). But now I have no idea why the last value isn't used by the function

```
    Public Function Getgctakeout(ByVal i_table As DataTable)
       table = i_table
       i = 0
       gctakeout = 0

    For Each row As DataRow In i_table.Rows

        gctakeout = gctakeout + Convert.ToDouble(row(4))

    Next row
        'MessageBox.Show(gctakeout)
    Return gctakeout
    End Function
```

This function does not use the value of the last row to calculate gctakeout

what in the name of the lord is wrong :)

Comment: Your code looks fine, a `For Each` should ensure every row is iterated over. When you debug does it not loop over the last row in the table?

Comment: Nothig wrong in this code. The only possible causes are on the i_table passed in. Check i_table.Rows.Count before the loop. Also a null value could trigger an exception.

Comment: I would disagree with earlier comments in that I don't think this code looks fine. Why are you using class member variables to do your calculation, when you are returning the sum at the end? You are also missing a return type for your function. All in all, this function looks like it could have a lot of 'side effects' especially if there is any concurrency in your app.

Comment: Have you tried using `Next` instead of `Next row`. Not sure but just guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `DataTable` is really filled correctly, you have two other options to get the sum.

1. Use the old [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method which works also with .NET < 2.0
2. Use `Linq-To-DatSet` and it's [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx)

1)

```
Dim Sum = CType(table.Compute("Sum(ColumnName)", Nothing), Double)
```

2)

```
Dim Sum = table.AsEnumerable().
                Sum(Function(row)row.Field(Of Double)("ColumnName"))
```